# Enable button only if one EditText was changed

Tags: button, android-studio, enable-if

I have an activity with few `EditText` fields that contain text already, and one button.

I want the button to be disabled unless at least one of the `EditText` fields was changed (if unclear, in other words, enable button only if at least one of fields was changed...)

How to do it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of now is to put a listener to each of the EditText fields, and whenever it is fired, enable the button.

Answer (score 0):

store the contents already in `EditText` in variables, then after an `EditText` is edited check the new value with value stored in variable. if they are not same enable the button